# Can't get the sum of all numbers below n divisible by either 3 or 5

Tags: python

The following program gives the sum of all numbers that are divisible by either 3 or 5 below a given input number. The problem I am facing is that it doesn't correctly output sum for n = 100. The solution for n = 100 should be 2318, but my program gives me 2633. I can't figure out the problem, since it also gives the right sum for n = 10 correctly.

```
    #!/bin/python3

import sys
import math
arr = []
sum1 = 0 
sum2 = 0

t = int(input().strip())

while t < 1 or t > 10**5:
    print()
    t = int(input().strip())

for i in range(t):
    n = int(input().strip())
    arr.append(n)
    
for x in range (0, len(arr)):
    sum1 = 0
    sum2 = 0
 
    for b5 in range (0, arr[x], 5):
        sum1 = sum1 + b5
        
    for b3 in range (0, arr[x], 3):
        sum2 = sum2 + b3
    sum = sum1 + sum2
    print(sum)
```

Edit:
After all the good feedback, I came up with the idea to exclude the numbers that are being added twice in the original program, by adding an if statement as follows:

```
for b5 in range (0, arr[x], 5):
    sum1 = sum1 + b5
    if b5%3 == 0:
        sum1 = sum1 - b5
    
for b3 in range (0, arr[x], 3):
    sum2 = sum2 + b3
```

It isn't as elegant, but I still wanted to add it.

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: n = 10 and n = 100, 100 giving a wrong sum

Comment: Problem is most likely that - for example - for numbers < 100, 45 is included in both the sum where divisible by 3 and 5, that is, it's included twice. Below 10, no number is divisible by both so gives the right result.

Comment: You don't have to loop and pick in your second *edits* - because you're only interested in the *sum* ```total```.  just sum directly like @trincot post.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this counts double the numbers that are *both* multiples of 3 and of 5.

The easy solution is to subtract those from your sum.

Note that your loops are bit overkill, as the `sum` function can take the `range` expression directly as argument.

So:

```
n = 100

total = sum(range (0, n, 5)) + sum(range (0, n, 3)) - sum(range (0, n, 3*5))
print(total)
```

You can avoid the (implicit) loops by solving this with the formula for [Triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number):

```
def sum_mul(n, divisor):
    quot = (n - 1) // divisor
    return (quot * (quot + 1) // 2) * divisor

n = 100

total = sum_mul(n, 3) + sum_mul(n, 5) - sum_mul(n, 3*5)
print(total)
```

Comment: Spot on.  Maybe can consider *set* and *union* too.  (Save the subs ops)

Comment: Even better is using triangular numbers.

Comment: Similar  ```ans =  sum(  ( set(range(0, n, 5)) | set(range(0, n, 3))))```

Comment: Yes, but that still has the iterations..

Answer (score 1):

The excellent @trincot answers are clever Python. For completeness, the looping answer below shows how your original logic should have been structured.

```
mysum = 0
limit = 100

for x in range(limit):
    if (x % 5 == 0) or (x % 3 == 0):
        mysum += x
```

Comment: Let's try to avoid Python *built-in* ```sum``` as the variable name.

Comment: Quite. So `or` avoids finding both 3 and 5 for numbers such as 45. If each condition had been used in a separate `if` expression then it would have picked up each of 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90 twice so a total of 315 too many which is why the questioners code found 2633 instead of 2318.